# voice recording ui in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am creating a voice recording module in android , now what i am trying to do is to create voice recording user interface as follows , preciously the mic image , and when ever the user speaks we can show animated the level of its amplitude ( i don't know what to call the intensity of voice ).

the following image is the default voice recorded supplied in android samsung phones , i dont want to use the default voice recording service by using its intent as it has its own restrictions

[image]

Comment: This is not the default recorder app in Android. It is the default app in Samsung Mobiles I believe.

Comment: Ohh sorry then i didn't know it

Comment: @Hunt did you manage to work it out ? please share with us if you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the default recorder app in Android. It is the default app in Samsung Mobiles I believe.

Also there is no pause API available for recording in Android. You must do some low level coding to achieve that.

Comment: can u share some code for "Low Level Coding" to get the pause option.